# DXA 1.5 java - BrokerResultFilter.class missing

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-1.5

Could you please suggest me for the below exception for DXA 1.5

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationResolver com.tdca.wcm.controller.AdminController.localizationResolver; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tridionLocalizationResolver': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationFactory com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.localizationFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localizationFactoryImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProvider com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.contentProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.dd4t.core.factories.PageFactory com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider.dd4tPageFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tridionSpringConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.dd4t.providers.PageProvider com.sdl.webapp.config.TridionSpringConfig.pageProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pageProvider' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/webapp/tridion/SpringContextConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPageProvider com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SpringContextConfiguration.pageProvider()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.filter.BrokerResultFilter

Thanks,
Jyotirmay

Comment: I maybe be off the mark here, but this package "com.sdl.web" doesn't exist for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. Mixed versions maybe?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some more detail/context to it? Just posting a stacktrace from an error log is not really helpful, as you can see by the lack of answers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to check your dd4t version, as well as the dxa-tridion provider module that you are loading, you must load only the dxa-tridion-2013sp1-provider

Because of project needs, we are checking to only upload the dd4t to the dd4t 2.1.2-DXA version and we are having the same issue. The problem is that the BrokerPageProvider, class included in the dd4t-provider, includes a dependency to com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.filter.BrokerResultFilter.

If you are using tridion sp1 2013 you are not using these libraries, then there is the crash. For our case, we needed to upgrade the jackson version, then we decided to check this version, the problem is that we are not compatible.